# How to use default values when inserting record using sql-processor

Tags: sql-processor

I am using [this](https://github.com/hudec/sql-processor/wiki) framework as my persistent tier which also generate sql statement. Now in statement.meta it generate me sql:

```
INSERT_TOURNAMENT(CRUD,in=Tournament,out=Tournament,tab=tournament)=
  insert into %%tournament (%ID, %NAME, %SEASON_ID, %FINAL_PROMOTING, %LOWER_PROMOTING, %WIN_POINTS, %PLAY_OFF_FINAL, %PLAY_OFF_LOWER, %MIN_PLAYERS_IN_GROUP, %SORT_TYPE, %PUBLISH)
  {= values (:id(seq=TOURNAMENT), :name, :season.id, :finalPromoting, :lowerPromoting, :winPoints, :playOffFinal, :playOffLower, :minPlayersInGroup, :sortType, :publish) }
;
```

in db I have defined some column as not null with default value. Now when I am inserting new record and when I didnt fill this value I want to use default value and not inserting null. Is there some option how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it when I use directive `metagen-optimize-insert TOURNAMENT;` then it generated select which I want